# Have 3 matrices of same dimensions - I want to get the highest value of each cell of the three different matrices

Tags: r, matrix, max, combiners

Basically I have 3 matrices of the same dimensions. They only consist of values 0 , 1, 2 ,3. I would like to create a new matrix that takes the highest value from each of the corresponding matrices.

For example, if the first row of the matrices are as follows:

```
A: 0 1 0 0 1
B: 2 0 0 2 0
C: 0 3 0 3 0
```

Final: `2 3 0 3 1`

I was trying to do a for function with apply but I couldn't get it working.

Edit: I think pmax is the function to do according to the comments.. Thanks! Im am just starting out and learning about R so sorry if this is a simple question.

Comment: Probably should look a little harder. Maybe search for `pmax`. If this is fruitless, please provide a reproducible example (use `dput`  on each matrix).

Comment: shouldn't the first column of the Final be a 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample data:

```
m1 <- matrix(sample(0:3, 12, replace = TRUE), 4)
m2 <- matrix(sample(0:3, 12, replace = TRUE), 4)             
m3 <- matrix(sample(0:3, 12, replace = TRUE), 4)
```

And the result

```
pmax(m1, m2, m3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    1    3
# [2,]    2    3    1
# [3,]    1    3    3
# [4,]    3    3    3
```